# How we can name the test case dynamically when using data provider for Allure report

Tags: testng, allure

We have test case name in data provider and wanted to print the same in Allure report. Currently it prints the same default test method name repeatedly for all the cases of data provider

Answer (score 2):

Please see below example how to dynamic set description and test name in Allure when using @DataProvider.

```
@Test(dataProvider = "getListOfCredentials", dataProviderClass = AuthenticationDataProvider.class)
public void loginUser(AuthenticationData authenticationData) {
    AllureLifecycle lifecycle = Allure.getLifecycle();
    lifecycle.updateTestCase(testResult -> testResult.setName("Test wrong login with username: "+authenticationData.getUsername()));
    lifecycle.updateTestCase(testResult -> testResult.setDescription("Test wrong login with password: "+authenticationData.getPassword()));
}
```

So, I have the Allure description and test title dynamic based on what credentials my data provider method will return each time the test will run using the object authenticationData.